# How do I convert a British biscuit recipe to a moister American style cookie?

Tags: cookies, texture, moisture, biscuits

I've got a triple choc biscuit recipe from my British mother. She's noted that it's a dry biscuit as it's meant to be enjoyed with a cup of tea.
My partner enjoys American style moist cookies. She prefers the gooey texture it provides.
I was wondering how I would convert the recipe to make my dry biscuits into gooey cookies?
The dry ingredients are cocoa, Sr flour, sugar, choc chips.
The wet ones are eggs, vanilla extract, butter, cooking chocolate melted.

Comment: Is there some aspect that you want to keep from your original cookie? Is there a reason why you don't you just search for a recipe for american style cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make some experiments if you need to add something or to change an igredients.

Cookies are chewy because they are moist. Easiest trick in the book - bake the cake for the first 1/10 of cooking time with temp 20% higher than in recipe WITH a bowl of water.

Other methods:

1. split sugar into two types. White and brown sugar. Let say
   50/50.  Brown sugar have molasses so it have more water in it.
2. Try adding soda. What you wrote down is very similar to
   black cake I made with the change of oil for butter and few tbs of
   soda. Mine is not very chewy but I prefer to add more cocoa than
   chocolate.  Soda help keep the moisture in.
3. lower the amount of flour or/and let the dough rest for a
   bit to develop gluten.
4. add wetness - so add extra egg white, or a spoon of
   yoghurt, or some water.